# Dealing with date format in zoo

Tags: r

I've a [csv data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwfiy4mPaO61SnpOUWp3MmJKLUU/view?usp=sharing)  with the following formats
[Stock prices over the period of Jan 1, 2015 to Sep 26, 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T4lP.png)

Now I use the following code to import the data as zoo object:

```
sensexzoo1<- read.zoo(file = "/home/bidyut/Downloads/SENSEX.csv", 
                           format="%d-%B-%Y",  header=T, sep=",")
```

It produces the following error:

> Error in read.zoo(file = "/home/bidyut/Downloads/SENSEX.csv", format =
>   "%d-%B-%Y",  :    index has 679 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6
>   7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
>   31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53
>   54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76
>   77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
>   100 ...

What is the wrong with this? Please suggest

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if this had something to do with month's language being different than your locale.

Comment: `read.zoo("SENSEX.csv", format="%d-%B-%Y", header=T, sep=",", FUN=as.Date)` I think the main issue is the null column at the end.. the lines in that csv file are all terminated by commas . If you add another column name , say "volume" , it will work correcly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the mismatch between the header and the data.  The header line has 5 fields and the remaining lines of the file have 6 fields:

```
head(count.fields("SENSEX.csv", sep = ","))
## [1] 5 6 6 6 6 6
```

When that happens it assumes that the first field of the data is the row names so by default the next field (which in fact contains the Open data) is assumed to be the time index.

We can address this in several alternative ways:

**1)** The easiest way to fix this is to add a field called Volume, say, to the header so that the header looks like this:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
```

**2)** If you have many files of this format so that it is not feasible to modify them we can read the data in without the headers and then add them on in a second pass.  The [, -5] drops the column of NAs and the [-1] on the second line drops the Date header.

```
z <- read.zoo("SENSEX.csv", format="%d-%B-%Y", sep = ",", skip = 1)[, -5]
names(z) <- unlist(read.table("SENSEX.csv", sep = ",", nrow = 1))[-1]
```

giving:

```
> head(z)
               Open     High      Low    Close
2015-01-01 27485.77 27545.61 27395.34 27507.54
2015-01-02 27521.28 27937.47 27519.26 27887.90
2015-01-05 27978.43 28064.49 27786.85 27842.32
2015-01-06 27694.23 27698.93 26937.06 26987.46
2015-01-07 26983.43 27051.60 26776.12 26908.82
2015-01-08 27178.77 27316.41 27101.94 27274.71
```

**3)** A third approach is to read the file in as text, use R to append ",Volume" to the first line and then read the text with `read.zoo`:

```
Lines <- readLines("SENSEX.csv")
Lines[1] <- paste0(Lines[1], ",Volume")
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",", format="%d-%B-%Y")
```

**Note:** The first few lines of SENSEX.csv are shown below to make this self-contained (not dependent on the link in the question which could disappear in the future):

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close
1-January-2015,27485.77,27545.61,27395.34,27507.54,
2-January-2015,27521.28,27937.47,27519.26,27887.90,
5-January-2015,27978.43,28064.49,27786.85,27842.32,
6-January-2015,27694.23,27698.93,26937.06,26987.46,
7-January-2015,26983.43,27051.60,26776.12,26908.82,
8-January-2015,27178.77,27316.41,27101.94,27274.71,
9-January-2015,27404.19,27507.67,27119.63,27458.38,
12-January-2015,27523.86,27620.66,27323.74,27585.27,
13-January-2015,27611.56,27670.19,27324.58,27425.73,
14-January-2015,27432.14,27512.80,27203.25,27346.82,
```